# How to use bootstraps x-editable in table rows?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I would like to use the bootstraps X-editable plugin. I retrieve server side data in my table and I would like to edit them in-line. As I see, X-editable is proposed to work with id's. Would be possible to handle this with multiple data?

The documentation:

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').editable();
});
```

What about if I have more usernames?

Comment: You don't need to use an element's id to initialize x-editable. Just set `class="username"` in your `a` tags and then use `$('.username').editable();`

Comment: you are right I made a test http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/FgqH6/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
```

change to

```
<a href="#" class="username">superuser</a>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').editable();
});
```

Change to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.username').editable();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You should use this feature also in Laravel applications

Answer (score 0):

if you have more usernames would be better change that names. 
You can set editable any element that you want. Just make a selector to do that. 
You can do it with data-* attributes..

Greatings,
Hugo Pedrosa

Answer (score 0):

Use **id** for `<table>`:

```
<table id="user" class="table table-striped">
<tr><td>
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
</td></tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user a').editable();
});
```

Comment: This does not work, the anchor link needs to be unique, so class must be used instead of id when calling editable();